# How to send Smileys/Emoticons with SMS in android Application

Tags: android

I am developing a SMS Application, but I have to add Smileys/Emoticons with the SMS. But I don't know how to do that.Please suggest any solution regarding the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep all the smiley's in the drawable folder and use a `HashMap` to link the `resource_id` with the `smiley character` and use `ImageSpan` to attach the image with text inside a TextView. I had just created a demo for the same, you can find it from [`here`](https://github.com/lalit3686/SimleyPopUpDemo).

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use [ImageSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html) in your Textboxes to convert the smileys.